# How could I prove that $X$ is not compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

How could I prove this claim?

If $X$ is a first countable compact space and $p$ is not isolated in $X$, then $X\setminus \{p\}$ is not compact.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your definition, does compact imply Hausdorff?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Yes, it is. I‘m sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces must be closed.  Since $p$ is not isolated, this means that $\{ p \}$ is not open, or, equivalently, $X \setminus \{ p \}$ is not closed.  Thus $X \setminus \{ p \}$ cannot be compact.  (First-countability is not needed.)

Answer (score 2):

The result is false in general if $X$ is not assumed to be Hausdorff: a counterexample is $\omega$ with the cofinite topology. I will therefore assume that $X$ is Hausdorff and therefore $T_3$>

Assuming that $X$ is Let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a local base at $p$ such that $B_n\supsetneqq\operatorname{cl}B_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\omega$, and for $n\in\omega$ let $U_n=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}B_n$. Then $\{U_n:n\in\omega\}$ is an open cover of $X\setminus\{p\}$ with no finite subcover.